# Pass ngFor variable to nested component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

Inside my parent component **Property-page.component.html** I iterate through `propertiesArray` and want to show a list of `property-card` based on it.

```
<property-card
    *ngFor="let propertiesItem of propertiesArray"
    [propertiesItem] = "propertiesItem"
></property-card>
```

**Property-card.component.ts**:

```
export class PropertyCardComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() propertiesItem: any;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**Property-card.component.html**:

```
<div class="upload-card-content">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{ propertiesItem.id }}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>{{ propertiesItem.designation }}</mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-footer>
            <span class="icon-icon_calendar"></span>
            Period:
            <span class="period">{{ propertiesItem.period }}</span>
        </mat-card-footer>
</div>
```

**Question**

For some reason; `propertiesItem` is `undefined` in the child component. Could someone explain what I've missed?

Comment: What `propertiesArray` looks like ?

Comment: Maybe `propertiesArray` holds `undefined`, eg. `[1, 2, undefined, 4]`

Comment: There is a problem with passage of the variable ```propertiesItem```, because when do not separate ```property-card``` from the Parent Component (make one common component), ```propertiesItem``` work

Comment: `propertiesItem` is `undefined` if you `console.log` it in `ngOnInit()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `*ngIf` to the child component, like this:

```html
<div class="upload-card-content" *ngIf="propertiesItem">
      <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ propertiesItem.id }}</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>{{ propertiesItem.designation }}</mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-footer>
          <span class="icon-icon_calendar"></span>
          Period:
          <span class="period">{{ propertiesItem.period }}</span>
      </mat-card-footer>
</div>
```